# problems with a sequence table for GCSE worksheet

Tags: tables

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccc|c|}
\hline
0 & $$1^{st}$& & $2^{nd}$ & & $3^{rd}$ & & $4^{th}$ & & $5^{th}$ & Position of terms (n)\\
&$\uparrow$ && $\uparrow$ && $\uparrow$ & &$\uparrow$&& $\uparrow$ &&&\\
&3 && 5 && 7 && 9 & &11 &Terms in sequence\\
&&$\vee$&& $\vee$ && $\vee$ && $\vee$&&&&\\
$\uparrow$&& 2 && 2 && 2 && 2 && Gap&&&\\
1 &&&&&&&&&&Term before the first term\\
&$\vee$&&&&&&&&&\\
&2&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your question?

Comment: would like to either use better code and to make the table more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the table is sparse, I'd first reduce the intercolumn space, except between the first and second columns.

I'd avoid the vertical rules that add nothing to clarity and use 1st and so on, instead of the Victorian age style that users of a known word processor from a known software company started to use because the developers of that software liked it and made the software do it *automatically*.

With some *ad hoc* local commands you can also ease the input and see the whole alignment in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newcommand{\up}{$\uparrow$}
\newcommand{\ve}{$\vee$}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}cccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
0   & 1st &     & 2nd &     & 3rd &     & 4th &     & 5th & Position of terms ($n$)    \\
    & \up &     & \up &     & \up &     & \up &     & \up                              \\
    &  3  &     &  5  &     &  7  &     &  9  &     & 11  & Terms in sequence          \\
    &     & \ve &     & \ve &     & \ve &     & \ve                                    \\
\up &     &  2  &     &  2  &     &  2  &     &  2  &     & Gap                        \\
1   &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     & Term before the first term \\
    & \ve \\
    &  2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that makes it a lot easier to use.